Cap touch sensor reflash mode TTP233H-BA6
I have a hardware device us the TTP233H-BA6 capacitive touch sensor. When building multiple devices I'm noticing about 20% of devices will not trigger the cap touch sensor right away. It takes a lot of tries and generally a wait time of what seems to be 30+ seconds until it will finally trigger like you'd expect. In trying to figure out what may be the issues (firmware vs. hardware vs. both)... I found that the cap sensor has a 4sec reflash mode and I'm thinking maybe the chip is cycling in reflash mode one or more times in a row that are causing the delay. There is very little information I can find on the internet about this reflash mode, how to trigger it or how to know it's running in order to try to figure out if this is what is causing the delay. Can anyone elaborate on their experience with this chip to help me try to force my devices into a reflash mode  state purposefully to see if this may be what's happening on my devices?
I tried searching the internet about reflash state, but have not found any helpful information or experience with the chip.

Probably more suitable for https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ although they will prompt you for schematics.
